# two incoming packets in response to requests sent by different browser, how does each browser knows which one is intended to it?

Tags: networking

Let's say two requests are sent to a server the same second from two different browsers - how do the browsers know which packet is intended toit.

Comment: This problem is managed by TCP, which allow over-layers to make high-reliability communication. What are you intended to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question doesn't arise. Browser A doesn't see any data intended for browser B. TCP only delivers data to the socket at the end of the connection it was sent on.

Answer (score 0):

Browse does'nt care which is intended to it, browser will simply communicate through its **socket address**.
You can imagine it as, Ip Address which distinguishes a unique system in network, but TCP/UDP will distinguish within that system based on Port. Thats how TCP manages to provide data to 2 different browsers at the same time within the system.

> TCP/IP transport layer addressing is accomplished using TCP and UDP ports. Each port number within a particular IP device identifies a particular software process.
>   [Multiplexing and Demultiplexing Using Ports](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPPortsTransportLayerTCPUDPAddressing.htm)

From [Port Explained](http://www.linuxjunkies.org/articles/port_explained.html)

> By knowing the IP address in use, a program is therefore able to send data to another computer. But an essential factor has been left out. How the receiving computer can know which program to use for the data it receives. For this reason there is a system of port numbers, also known as ports. With each transmission of data, the data package must contain the receiver's IP, and also the port number of the program which is responsible.